# How to open Pdf from application to default viewer?

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, android-7.0-nougat, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to open pdf from my application to default document viewer in Nougat.

This is not duplicate cause I have different problem than others so read till end .

**What I've tried:**

I know i have to use FileProvider , Make provider.xml , get runtime permission about accessing that app .

in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

my **GenericFileProvider**

```
public class GenericFileProvider extends FileProvider {}
```

**provider_path.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

openign pdf by this

```
 val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"pdfname")

            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
            val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,  BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)

           context.grantUriPermission("com.google.android.apps.docs", uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)


            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
            context.startActivity(intent)
```

My problem is :

> at the time of viewing my pdf its first character has been changed .
>   so it generates file not found exception

when i'm using this provider path . **it delete my first character of pdf name**

```
 my file name is  : /storage/emulated/0on the matter of.pdf
 my uri is : content://mypackage.provider/root/storage/emulated/0on%20the%20matter%20of.pdf
so pdf name is : n the matter of.pdf
```

when using provider_path this .

```
<root-path
           name="root"
           path="/" />
```

**it adds 0 to my pdf name**

```
 my file name is  : /storage/emulated/0on the matter of.pdf
 my uri is : content://mypackage.provider/root/storage/emulated/0on%20the%20matter%20of.pdf
so pdf name is : 0on the matter of.pdf
```

What should i do to get pdf name properly. what  should i have to write in provider path .

Comment: the path is not correct I think It should be `/storage/emulated/0/on the matter of.pdf`, not `/storage/emulated/0on the matter of.pdf`

Comment: So you probably should use: `val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/pdfname")`

Comment: thanks @VladyslavMatviienko it solved that first character issuie but still i got 

`E/PdfLoader: Can't load file (doesn't open)  Display Data [PDF : In the matter of Alipurduar Enterprises Ltd .pdf] +ContentOpenable, uri: content://my package.provider/external_files/In%20the%20matter%20of%20Alipurduar%20Enterprises%20Ltd.pdf`

Comment: Try a filename without spaces.

Comment: @greenapps  i've tried with name abcd.pdf  but still got `com.google.android.apps.docs E/DisplayData: openFd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT for abcd.pdf` . its open properly from file manager but not from my app

Comment: @greenapps my bad . I solved that issue. Thanks Both for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  @VladyslavMatviienko and @greenapps . I've solved my issue.

As pointed out by @VladyslavMatviienko . I was passing wrong file path .

```
val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"pdfname")
```

Instead of

```
val file = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/pdfname")
```

So its showing that `java.io.FileNotFoundException:`

So everything posted in my question is working fine for displaying pdf from my app to viewer in Oreo. So maybe it will help someone.